# Discovering an artefacts' native dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I have recently begun maintaining an Android app that is not compliant with Google's requirement for 64-bit native libraries. The app itself does not directly depend on native code but in the generated apk a native library named **libcproxy** gets included. I can only assume that this is needed by one of the apps dependencies but so far I have not had any luck in finding the artefact in question. The shared library also seems a bit elusive as I have not been able to find many references to it online.

Is there perchance a gradle command or similar that can shed some light on which artefact includes the library?

I have tried excluding the shared library in the hope, that I might get an unsatisfied link error but so far I have not been able to make the app crash due to missing the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a dependency tree with :

```bash
gradlew app:dependencies
```